# Can a "jevents" tag be created to minimise the misuse of the "jevent" tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Assuming the `jevent` tag was created for questions relating to the JEvent Class in the API http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JEvent.html, could a `jevents` tag be created for questions relating to the JEvents event calendar extension?

Currently the `jevent` tag is only being used to tag questions relating to the extension: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jevent

There are already tags for other extensions such as `akeebabackup` and `sh404sef` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I don't think we will have questions regarding JEvent anytime soon.

I have renamed the tag

> jevent => jevents

and added a proper description so that we know what is it for.

Comment: Agreed. I would guess that any questions related to the JEvent class will likely be worded around "plugins" more than that class name.